Definitions of convergence of Riemannian metrics - ¿Equivalence?
I'm learning and working with convergence of (semi-)Riemannian metrics on a smooth manifold M.
I've encountered two different definitions which are referred to as Cheeger-Gromov convergence. They usually include diffeomorphisms to study intrinsic convergence of a sequence of (pointed) Riemannian manifolds $(M_i, g_i)$. Since I'm working on a fixed manifold M, one could drop these diffeomorphisms.
The first definition is used in the study of Ricci flow, and can be found in Chow et al. The Ricci flow: Techniques and Applications Part I (Def 3.1 and 3.2)

Definition 1. Let $\{U_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an exhaustion of a smooth manifold $M^n$ by open sets,   $g_i$ a semi-Riemannian metric on $U_i$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$, and $g_\infty$ a semi-Riemannian metric on $M$.
We say that $\{(U_i, g_i)\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ \emph{converges in $C^{p}, p\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\},$ to $g_\infty$ uniformly on compact sets} if for any compact subset $K \subset M$ and every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $i_0$ such that for $i \geq i_0$ {\bf  and non-negative integer $\alpha$ }
$$\sup_{0 \leq \alpha < p+1} \sup_{x \in K} | \nabla^{\alpha} (g_i - g_\infty)|_h < \epsilon,$$
where $h$ is an auxiliary Riemannian metric and $|\cdot |_h$ denotes the norm induced by $h$ in the space of tensors at each point $x$.

The second definition, although not exactly as I state it here, I have found is more commonly used for $C^{m, \alpha}$ convergence and can be found in M. Anderson's https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0208079

Definition 2. A sequence of metrics $g_i$ on an $n$-manifold $M$ is said to converge in $C^p$ to a limit metric $g_\infty$ on $M$ if there is a locally finite collection of charts $\{\varphi_k\}$ covering $M$, such that
$$(g_i)_{\alpha \beta} \to (g_\infty)_{\alpha \beta}$$
in the $C^p$-norm. Here $(g_i)_{\alpha \beta}$ and $(g_\infty)_{\alpha \beta}$ denote the local component functions of $g_i$ and $g_\infty$ in the charts $\varphi_k$.

Are these two definitions equivalent? If not, is there a definition that uses coordinates that is equivalent to Definition 1?
Thanks a lot.

They are equivalent. First, you prove that the first definition is independent of the background metric $h$. Second, to prove that the second implies the first, you use the charts to construct a global background metric $h$. To prove the converse, you use the fact that if every chart has compact closure, then the background metric $h$ has positive upper and lower bounds with respect to the coordinates on a given chart.

Thanks a lot! Do you know any reference with a proof? It seems to be that it should be written somewhere but I can't find it

No. I suggest you work out the details yourself.
